# Research papers regarding disinterval analysis

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, na.numerical-analysis

I'm trying to implement a disinterval analysis similiar to what is described in [Clousot: Static Contract Checking with Abstract Interpretation](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/138696/Main.pdf) (under section 5.2) - and I'm trying to find some papers describing the abstract operators (+, -, join, meet - etc) - however I have been unable to dig these up.

Are any of you aware of such papers and could you please link me to them?

Answer (score 1):

You could give a shot at Ermedahl & Sjodin: [Interval analysis of C-variables using Abstract Interpretation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.3333).

Comment: I am trying to find the information on disintervals - as described in the referenced paper: "Elements of Disintervals are normalized sequences of non-overlapping intervals...". Ie a powerset of intervals with some constraints in order to make them nice to play with.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just referring to an article that describes the technique for simple intervals. However the paper you refer to explicitly says that the case for multiple intervals is quite similar to the case with a single interval. Have you tried working out the rules yourself?